# Alert not appearing if i put the route under auth middleware group

Tags: ajax, laravel

I am not allowing the user to submit the form if not logged in. So, giving the alert to login.

**Jquery and Ajax**

```
 $(document).on('submit', '.bet', function (e) 
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        var frm = $(this);
        $.ajax({
                type: frm.attr('method'),
                url: frm.attr('action'),
                data: frm.serialize(),
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data)
                {
                    if(data == 'notloggedin')
                    {
                            alert('You must login first!');
                    }
                    else if(data==true)
                    {
                            swal('Bet Success! The details has been sent to your email!');
                    }
                    else if(data=='dateexpired')
                    {
                          swal('The match bet time expired!');
                    }
                 }
         });       
    });
```

**Controller:**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    if($request->ajax())
    {
        if(!Auth::check())
        {
                echo json_encode('notloggedin');die;
        }
    ....
```

This went all good. But, if I put this route under auth middleware the alert is not appearing. And in the developer's tool i see `unauthorized action`. Yes. it is obvious but i still want the alert to appear.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
          Route::post('/bet/store','BetController@store');
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Error is not shown because if the auth middleware fails the response indicates that the request was not successful ( so success method gets not executed ). In this case you have to use .fail() method.

```
    var jqXHR = $.ajax({
            type: frm.attr('method'),
            url: frm.attr('action'),
            data: frm.serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data)
            {
                if(data == 'notloggedin')
                {
                        alert('You must login first!');
                }
                else if(data==true)
                {
                        swal('Bet Success! The details has been sent to your email!');
                }
                else if(data=='dateexpired')
                {
                      swal('The match bet time expired!');
                }
             }
     }); 

jqXHR.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
   if(jqXHR.status == 401) {
     alert('unauthorized');
   } 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

that's because request is returned (401) from the middleware and controller action is never executed. also middleware is right place for this check why don't you return unauthorised response from auth middleware ? something like this

**App\Http\Middleware\Auth**

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($this->auth->guest()) {
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            return response()->json(['notloggedin']);
        }

        return redirect()->guest('login')->withErrors(['You must login first.']);
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

please note that this will return a status 200 for ajax request but I see you are using `success` function so it would work. You can also return a 401 with

```
if ($request->ajax()) {
      return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
}
```

and use `error` method on jQuery

Comment: I would not use error method as it is deprected and removed sind jQuery 3.0